# Javascript prototype override

Tags: javascript

I have this code that allows me to return a string about the posts connected to a particular post. I tried to use the bracket and dot notation in accessing properties below in the list part (`list=list+this["connectionsTo"[i]].postNum+"\n";`) but doesn't work. But then when I used the double dot notation, it worked, why? I believe those two are the same.

```
function Fencepost(x, y, postNum) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.postNum = postNum;
  this.connectionsTo = [];
}

Fencepost.prototype = {
  sendRopeTo: function(connectedPost) {
    this.connectionsTo.push(connectedPost);
  },
  removeRope: function(removeTo) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.connectionsTo.length; i++) {
      if (this.connectionsTo[i].postNum != removeTo) {
        temp.push(this.connectionsTo[i]);
      }
    }
    this.connectionsTo = temp;
  },
  movePost: function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  },
  valueOf: function() {
  return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x +
                   this.y * this.y);
  }
};

Fencepost.prototype.toString=function(){
var list="";
for(var i=0;i<this.connectionsTo.length;i++){
list=list+this["connectionsTo"[i]].postNum+"\n";
}
  return "Fence post #"+this.postNum+":\nConnected to posts:\n"+list+"Distance from ranch: "+this.valueOf()+" yards";
};

var post10=new Fencepost(3,4,10);
var post11=new Fencepost(5,7,11);
var post12=new Fencepost(6,7,12);
var post13=new Fencepost(8,9,13);
post10.sendRopeTo(post11);
post10.sendRopeTo(post12);
post10.sendRopeTo(post13);
console.log(post10.toString());
```

Comment: "doesn't work".  Ok.  What error did you get?  Check the javascript console when you try to execute this code and report back what you find.

Comment: What is "*double dot notation*"?

Comment: "anything"[n] isn't going to work the way you expect. Not sure what double dot notation is.

Comment: Hi mister I'm new to JS (started 10 days ago) and this is what I find in JS Bin:"error"
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'postNum' of undefined
    at Fencepost.toString (hezecawilo.js:38:35)
    at hezecawilo.js:50:45
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.41.10.min.js:1:13926
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.41.10.min.js:1:10855"

Comment: `"connectedTo"[i]` evaluates to the i-th character of "connectedTo"

Comment: ya mister I edited the question, that was supposed to be ["connectionsTo"[i]].postNum, still doesnt work

Comment: `"connectionsTo"[i]` will return a character at the i position. I believe you wanted `this["connectionsTo"][i]`

Comment: `property 'postNum'` is missing because `this[c] .. this[o] .. this[n]` are all undefined.  You're trying to get `this["connectionsTo"][i]`, but as Bergi pointed out, you're getting the individual characters of the string `connectionsTo` instead.

Comment: Thank you :D. I tried it and it worked :)

Comment: The logic of *removeRope* is broken. It assigns a new array to *this.connectionsTo*, but any existing reference to that property will continue to reference the old (unmodified) array. You should *splice* the match from *connectionsTo*, not create and assign a new array from the non-matches (which is illogical, inefficient and likely the source of future obscure bugs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are iterating over the `this.connectionsTo` array, you are looking for

```
this["connectionsTo"][i]
```

or [the equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

```
this.connectionsTo[i]
```

instead of

```
this["connectionsTo"[i]]
```

which indexes the string, and then takes that character for the property of `this`.

Comment: @MarkLemuelGenita The edit concerns `"connectedTo"` vs `"connectionsTo"`, which is not what I am talking about

Comment: a follow-up question mister, why sometimes JS Bin requires me to use bracket and dot notation (accessing a property of an object within an object) and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) I had linked in my answer. You can always use bracket notation, but for constant identifier-named properties dot notation is easier to read.